# StartsWith not working with integer data type

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am having **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** while running the code below, where **lotId** is of integer type:

```cs
inventories = inventories.Where(u =>  u.lotId.ToString().StartsWith(param.Lot));
```

It used to work in **netcoreapp2.0** but not working in **netcoreapp3.1**

Comment: [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) your code to see which object is null. It might be `inventories` or `u` or `param`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it likely worked before was because you were running EF Core 2.x which enabled client-side evaluation by default, where EF Core 3.1+ have it disabled by default. You can enable it for that DbContext instance, or better, consider an approach that doesn't result in a client-side evaluation. For instance if your lot  IDs are 7 digit numbers where the first digit denotes a Lot, then calculate a range to compare:

```
var lotStart = param.Lot * 1000000;
var lotEnd = lotStart + 999999;

inventories = inventories.Where(u =>  u.lotId >= lotStart && u.lotId <= lotEnd);
```

This assumes that the first single digit was used to group lots. Client-side evaluation should be avoided where possible because it results in returning far more data to be processed in memory. A client-side eval version as you had it would be returning *all* inventory records with whatever filtering it might be able to do, then filter out the lot ID check after all of those Lots are loaded.